# Fork+DBI and statement handles

Tags: perl, fork, dbi

#### Situation

So I know that the connection gets shared across the processes and I can't use the connection I opened before the fork in the childprocesses.

I also know that perl complains when I try to do something like this:

```
my $sth = $dbConn->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
$dbConn->disconnect();
while(my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array){
    print @row,"\n";
}
```

because I try to disconnect while the statement handle is still active.

#### Why does this work then:

```
my $sth = $dbConn->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
while(my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array){
    my $pid = fork; 
    if(not defined $pid){
        warn "Could not fork\n";
        next;  # abort loop
    }
    if($pid){
        #Parent: Do nothing
    }
    else{ 
        #do stuff
        exit;
    }
}
```

If the child closes it on exit shouldn't perl complain about a statement handle still being active? I also made sure that the execution of some processes is over before the loop is fully iterated and thought it might complain then but it didn't. Shouldn't I fetch array refs and iterate using them instead of my demonstrated approach in this scenario?

Comment: I can reproduce that this works on 5.20 and Ubuntu.

Comment: Looks like it's not calling `disconnect` implicitly at the `exit` neither in the child nor the parent with the sqlite that I am trying. If you do `$dbConn->disconnect` in the child, it will complain.

Comment: @simbabque I wonder why that doesn't happen. If you try to use dbConn after the loop it says "connection has gone away" which makes sense but if that happened it should complain mid loop iteration as well. Do you know if there's any danger in using it like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update

You say in your comment above that the child processes *do* close the parent's database handle, so the only question is why there is no message about still-active statement handles associated with the closing of the handle

That is because the child process will *also* first close the statement handles on termination before closing the database handle, so there is no error condition to report

---

You don't say what database driver you're using, and it's my guess that you simply happen to have a well-behaving one

The documentation for the `DBI` module says this

> For ***some drivers***, when the child process exits the destruction of inherited handles cause the corresponding handles in the parent process to cease working.

so perhaps the driver you're using isn't one of those drivers

An alternative is that the code connecting to the database sets the `AutoInactiveDestroy` flag. It forces the `DESTROY` method to check whether the current PID is the same as one that created the database and statement handles, and is recommended practice for all new code anyway

Comment: Ok that makes sense thanks. However regarding your update: Why would the loop continue after the statement handle is being closed on exit of the child which finished first?

Comment: @R6D1H2: I don't know. Have you checked whether the full set of rows is processed? Is there more than one row in your selection? Or it may be that the `fetchrow_array` call just silently fails after the first child has exited, which will happen if `DESTROY` just calls `finish` on the statement handles. You should check `$sth->{Active}` to see the state of the handle.

Comment: yes the full set of rows is processed. As mentioned in the post I even made sure that processes exit before the loop is done to test exactly this case.

Comment: @R6D1H2: Okay, then I'm guessing that the driver caches the entire `select` result and simply has to pass it back in chunks when a `fetchrow` is called. That would work even if the handle has been disconnected. I can't say much more without knowing what driver we're dealing with here and reading how it's coded.

Comment: Mysql. That was what I suspected as well but I wanted to ask the question because I wasn't sure about the safety of using this method (since I get errors with my first piece of code which it should cache as well?).

Comment: @R6D1H2: You shouldn't use this method. It is undocumented and unreliable. You should set `$dbConn->{AutoInactiveDestroy} = 1` when you make the connection. That way only the process that created a handle will automatically destroy it, and your handles will stay intact and useable after the `while` loop.

Comment: I tested it the way I wrote it in my post and was very surprised that it worked, that's why I asked. I was going to use refs from fetchall_arayref in the real script. The DBI version is too old to support AutoInactiveDestroy but I'll use InactiveDestroy. Thanks!